# Авторизация на сайте через телеграм, без виджета

Tags: telegram-bot

Стоит задача, авторизации через бота телеграм, но без виджета, чтобы после команды /login, отсылал уникальный ссылку авторизации , с хеш, активировал webhook на сайте, пишу код путь domain/api/index.php

Сам код

```
try {
$tBot = new \TelegramBot\Api\Client($token);

$tBot->command('login', function ($message) use ($tBot) {
$chat_id = $message->getChat()->getId();
$user_name = $message->getChat()->getUsername();
$contact = $message->getContact();
$hash = hash('sha256', $user_name);
$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$r_message = "Chat id: ".$chat_id."\n";
$r_message.= "Username: ".$user_name."\n";
$r_message.= "Link for auth: ".$protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/login/?accept='.$hash."\n";
$tBot->sendMessage($chat_id, $r_message);
});
$tBot->run();
} catch (\TelegramBot\Api\Exception $e) {
$e->getMessage();
}
```

После, бот не реагирует на /login, кто знает в чем причина, буду благодарен